# music ecommerce shop?

Tags: ecommerce, looking-for-a-script, music

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Ecommerce Script Should I Use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30150/which-ecommerce-script-should-i-use)

i have a client that wants to make a music store, from which you can donwload a track for a price, or buy a new cd to be shipped, users should be able to have a preview of a track too!.

Was considering prestashop, was wondering if someone had a suggestion on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would use Magento. I've used it, and it's absolutely brilliant. Very nice piece of software!

Answer (score 0):

If you know joomla or drupal try virtuemart or ubercart.
Magento is very good but also very hard to customize.
Zen-cart is also a good option if above is too difficult.